# Docker: difference between selenium/node-chrome-debug and selenium/standalone-chrome

Tags: docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a docker-compose and I need to connect a container to a chrome connection. I am not sure which image I should use. Could you advise please which one is for this purpose between selenium/node-chrome-debug and selenium/standalone-chrome?

Answer (score 1):

`selenium/standalone-chrome` - Selenium standalone with chrome installed.

`selenium/node-chrome` - Grid node with Chrome installed, needs to be connected to a Grid Hub.

`selenium/standalone-chrome-debug` - Selenium standalone with Chrome installed, and runs VNC Server.

`selenium/node-chrome-debug` - Grid node with Chrome installed and VNC Server, needs to be connected to a Grid Hub.

[Click Here to see table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSbyN.png)

Comment: debug versions are now deprecated because debug utilities have been integrated into the normal images.  So use node-chrome instead of node-chrome-debug.